# How to move marker from one coordinate without go off road in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on google map and i am moving marker on map by setting marker position with new coordinate i got from server.

But here my issue is marker is going off road and direct goes to new location it's not following the road.

Here my requirement is marker should pass through the road to move one point to other point.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(2.0, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    self.marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
}
self.mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.lat, longitude: self.lon, zoom: 15))
self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.lon)
CATransaction.commit()
self.marker.map = self.mapView
```

Here is code that i have used for setting marker on map.

Comment: how frequently you are updating the marker location?

Comment: @HardikS location is coming from server and here i am setting this location and move marker to new position but when there is turn on road the marker is not move via road it's just cross the map.

Comment: It takes extra logic and more coordinates from server if you want to do this.. By default it will move pin to straight direction from one point to another.

Comment: but some time i get big distance coordinate this why this is happen. is there not any  way that marker not move direct to that location and go through road. @Hima

Comment: No, you should have all the points from server on which you want to display marker, it will not automatically move to the route.

Comment: you will have to use the directions api to get the path to the new location, then move the marker with that path.